# PHP code for displaying alternate image if custom field is not populated

Tags: php, image, wordpress, placeholder, custom-fields

I am trying to display what might be called a placeholder image if an image custom field has not been provided

I've got this far but am a bit stuck. The output is showing the code. Here is the PHP I am using.

```
$my_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_images', true);

if( isset($my_image) && $my_image != '') {
    echo '<img src="'.$my_image.'" width="230px" height="175px" />';
} else { 
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Poor.png">';
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you're surrounding your PHP code with `<?php /* code */ ?>`?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by `The output is showing code`

Comment: Try rewriting  if statement like if strlen ($myimg) > 0 , assuming image path is correct and it exists

Comment: The better way IMO is to have a container element with a css background image (which will be hidden if there is an actual image). This might even help with your problem (like iight I do not fully understand what the problem actially is).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you used **short open tag** `<? /* your code */ ?>`. This setting is by default disabled and not recommended. Make sure you wrapped your code properly within `<?php /* your code */ ?>`.